# Start a new Thread when one has finished: why am I not in a new Thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

This is basically the code:

```
private void TaskGestioneCartelle()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GeneraListaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void GeneraListaCartelle()
{
    // ... code
}

private void GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopiaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => CopiaCartelleCompletato()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private void CopiaCartelle()
{
    // long operation...
}
```

in fact, when CopiaCartelle start, I'm not into new Thread, because it take much time, and UI is totally freeze (while on `GeneraListaCartelle()`, which take long time too, this doesnt happens). Also because I can write on Controls in the UI without using `InvokeRequired` and `MethodInvoker`.

I miss some points?

Comment: i suggest you dont use threating with that knowledge, its like shooting your own foot

Comment: I know I'm a noob on this ;) But what I need at the moment it's just this simple step...

Comment: I think the problem is `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. If you ever need to use the UI thread, use invoke where needed, don't use the same thread for your task.

Comment: Conrad can you give to me an example?

Comment: Are you using wpf or winforms?

Comment: @ConradClark: are you vanished? :)

Comment: The code in your question looks correct - it runs `CopiaCartelle` on a background thread pool thread. The only way that method can freeze the UI is if it explicitly marshals work back onto the UI thread. Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: Just a second @paizza :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing  `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopiaCartelle())`
 to the following:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopiaCartelle(),  CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default))
```

You're going into GeneraListaCartelleCompletata in a continuation on the UI thread, and it is scheduling the task on the UI thread it seems - putting TaskScheduler.Default will make it run back in its own thread.  (Just tested this to confirm)

Comment: Not sure about what you are showing to me here! Can you give an example?

Comment: Anyway yes, I call `CopiaCartelle` from UI too because I call it from `GeneraListaCartelleCompletata` (which is the "callback" of the `GeneraListaCartelle`. `GeneraListaCartelleCompletata` is on the UI, but the new Thread... seems it doesnt create it :O

Comment: Well, ok! But now into CopiaCartelle() I can't use the UI controls, like textbox. Neither with txtLog.InvokeRequired

Comment: of course, because its on another thread now - (though not sure why invoke wouldn't work) - the normal practice is to update the UI in the continuation.  Have a look at creating a task<T> (e.g. List<string>, etc. - and pass the task to your continuation which can update the UI.  It's not easy!

Comment: This because I using the "same Thread". I don't want this, I want to execute CopiaCartelle() in another thread, not the UI one.

Comment: No wait. You misunderstand I think! This actually USE the same thread (on CopiaCartelle() I can access to myTextBox.Text, which is in the UI. So I'm on the same thread: in fact the UI is frozen).

Comment: Well, but now the ContinueWith? I'd like to keep having it, that will execute back to the UI. Can I?

Comment: Oh well, just adding `.ContinueWith(t => CopiaCartelleCompletato(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());` ;)

Answer (score 0):

What @NDJ posted is right, I've made a quick example to show what's going on.

First off, the methods:

```
private static void TaskGestioneCartelle()
{            
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GeneraListaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private static void GeneraListaCartelle()
{
    //No sleep could block the thread UI because the task is being executed on a different Thread
    Debug.WriteLine("GeneraListaCartelle " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(4000);            
    mainForm.Invoke(new Action(() => bla.Text = "uno due tre, Genera Lista!"));            
}

private static void GeneraListaCartelleCompletata()
{
    //This is begin executed on the UI thread
    Debug.WriteLine("GeneraListaCartelleCompletata " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CopiaCartelle())
        .ContinueWith(t => CopiaCartelleCompletato()
        , CancellationToken.None
        , TaskContinuationOptions.None
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private static void CopiaCartelle()
{
    //This is begin executed on the UI thread (doesn't even show in the form 'cause the thread is blocked)
    Debug.WriteLine("CopiaCartelle " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(4000);   
    mainForm.Invoke(new Action(() => bla.Text = "Copia Cartelle \\o"));            
}

private static void CopiaCartelleCompletato()
{
    //This is begin executed on the UI thread
    Debug.WriteLine("CopiaCartelleCompletato " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(4000);   
    mainForm.Invoke(new Action(() => bla.Text = "Completato!"));
    //Stops blocking the UI thread
}
```

Now the form and components

```
    static Label bla = new Label()
    {
        Text = "Mama Mia, Gestione Cartelle!",
        Left = 100,
        Top = 100,
        Width=300
    };

    static Label hangOn = new Label()
    {
        Text="Hang loose"
    };

    static Form mainForm = new Form()
    {
        Width = 600,
        Height = 600
    };

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    mainForm.Controls.Add(bla);
    mainForm.Controls.Add(hangOn);
    mainForm.MouseMove += (o, e) => { hangOn.Left = e.X; hangOn.Top = e.Y; };
    Debug.WriteLine("UI Thread: "+ Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    TaskGestioneCartelle();

    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

First, run the application and keep moving your mouse. You'll notice the UI thread was blocked when `Hang Loose` Label stops following your mouse.

Now, if you check the `Output` from Debug, you'll see something similar to this:

```
UI Thread: 10
GeneraListaCartelle 6
GeneraListaCartelleCompletata 10
CopiaCartelle 10
CopiaCartelleCompletato 10
```

See? It's using the UI Thread to run your tasks, thus hanging your UI.

Now, change `TaskScheduler.FormCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to `TaskScheduler.Default`

Tada:

```
UI Thread: 8
GeneraListaCartelle 9
GeneraListaCartelleCompletata 10
CopiaCartelle 10
CopiaCartelleCompletato 11
```

On a note, see that I'm using `mainForm.Invoke` to invoke actions to be executed in the `UI Thread`, such as changing the Label Text.

If you have any more doubts, feel free to comment.